# Order my consulting by field of my contain

Tags: mysql, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.x

I want order by `proyecto_id` who is in my `ProyectosCategoraisTareas` and also order by my categoria `id`, this is my contain `Tareas.Categorias`.
I try this but not work.

```
$proyectostareas = $this->ProyectosCategoriasTareas
    ->find('all', [
        'contain' => [
            'Proyectos',
            'Tareas',
            'Tareas.Categorias' => [
                'order' => [
                    'Tarea.Categoria.id' => 'DESC'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
    ->where([
        'activa' => '1'
    ])
    ->order([
        'proyecto_id' => 'DESC'
    ]);
```

Comment: What are the associations from ProyectosCategoriasTareas to Tareas and Tareas to Categorias? And what does "not work" mean? Error or incorrect data structure?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Tareas.Categorias.id' in 'order clause'

Comment: You haven't answered about the associations. That's critical for understanding this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$proyectostareas = $this->ProyectosCategoriasTareas
            ->find('all')
            ->where([
                'activa' => '1'
            ])
            ->join([
                'Proyectos',
                'Tareas'])
            ->order([
                'proyecto_id DESC',
                'Tarea.Categoria.id DESC'
            ]);
```